# how to remove Dollar sign in the amount field in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

While entering data into the decimal amount field, it's coming with Dollar $ sign I don't need. How do I remove this sign or how to replcae with Rs.but it should not change anything in the database if its updating the database.

Code

```
  <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)</td>
```

Model

```
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(10, 2)")]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

Comment: If you don't want the currency sign, why did you add `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` in the first place?

Comment: ok let me try without [DataType(DataType.Currency)]. Thanks. its working.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(10, 2)")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```